# making AJAX call from phonegap

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

How can I test my app on PhoneGap using local server?

Here is the thing:

I am trying to make a simple AJAX GET request to my local machine (by IP):

```
var connectIP = "192.168.10.2:8088";
var url = "http://"+connectIP+"/ws/v1/cluster/info";
$.get(url, function(data, status){ /* */ });
```

It works fine in chrome browser on device, but fails to connect using PhoneGap app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried doing it from another machine on the network? It could be a security/restriction issue.

Comment: Works fine! Even work in browser on mobile only fails in PhoneGap

Comment: @Saeedses Have you added whitelist plugin and allow access origin in config.XML?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you add a fail callback in there to send it to console? (are you using phonegap desktop or phonegap cli?)

Comment: Thanks @DauntlessRob for the idea of using console. I figured out the issue. 
I was using **window.location.pathname ** for a switch statment. and this variable returns different value while running from PhoneGap App.